# Check whether a given substring is present in the given string

Tags: c, for-loop, c-strings, strcmp

I should write a program in C to check whether a given substring is present in the given string.  The code I wrote is below but it doesn't work.  Can anyone tell me where the problem is?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
   char str[30]="the test string";
   char sbstr[30]="test";
   char strcp[30];
   int len = strlen(str);
   int i=0;
   int p=0;

   while(i<len)
   {
       while (str[i] != '\0' && str[i] != ' ')
       {
             strcp[i] = str[i];
              ++i;
       }
       strcp[i] = '\0';

       p = strcmp(sbstr, strcp);

       if (p==0)
       {
           printf("exist");
           break;
       }

       ++i;
   }

}
```

Comment: That is not a remotely efficient algorithm.  There's no need to copy subsections of the 'haystack' string (the one being searched).  There is a standard C function [`strstr()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strstr.html) that does this job. Normally, your code would compare the current character in the haystack with the first character of the 'needle' string (the one being looked for). If there's a match, continue looking at subsequent characters in both the haystack and the needle until you reach the end of the needle (match) or the end of the haystack (mismatch).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know you've already accepted an answer, but here's a slightly more efficient way to do a substring comparison that does not involve making a copy of the candidate substring to begin with in each iteration.

```
char str[30]="the test string";
char sbstr[30]="test";
int len = strlen(str);
int sublen = strlen(sbstr);
int found = 0;
int i = 0;  // starting index in str to start comparing on

while (!found && sublen <= len) {
    found = 1;

    // found = !strncmp(str+i, sbstr, sublen);
    for (int j = 0; j < sublen; j++) {
        if (str[i+j] != sbstr[j]) {
           found = 0;
           break;
        }    
    }

    if (!found) {
        i++;
        len--;
    }
}

if (found) {
    printf("Exists starting at index %d\n", i);
}
```

And if you really want to get hardcore, there are well known algorithms such as the [Boyer–Moore string-search algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string-search_algorithm) which can search faster by using a table-lookup scheme IIRC.

Answer (score 1):

For the array strcp

```
char strcp[30];
```

you need to support a separate index.

Something like

```
   int j = 0;
   while (str[i] != '\0' && str[i] != ' ')
   {
         strcp[j++] = str[i++];
   }
   strcp[j] = '\0';
```

Pay attention to that there is standard C function `strstr` that can be used to perform the task.

Comment: can i ask why strcp[j++] = str[i++] i don't get this point very well

Comment: yes i know but i try to do it without the strstr function

Comment: @ibtissamelhammoumy The expression str[i++] in fact in this context is equivalent to str[i] and  i = i+1